# How to read any '.config' file in c# but its own

Tags: c#, configuration

How to read a .config file using `ConfigurationManager` or any other way.

Below is my code which gives the following error:

> 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.this
>   [System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty] is inaccessible due to
>   its protection level.'

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
//txtConfigFile gets a config file path at runtime
configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = txtConfigFile.FilePath;

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
//Configpath's value is assigned to a textbox named txtConfigPath
txtConfigPath = config.AppSettings["Configpath"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Configuration.AppSettings` returns an `AppSettingSections` object,  `AppSettingSections` is derived from `ConfigurationSection` which is derived from `ConfigurationElement` which defines a `this[]` operator as `protected internal`, which mean that it is "inaccessible due to its protection level."

You should try `AppSettings.Settings`:

```
txtConfigPath = config.AppSettings.Settings["Configpath"];
```

Comment: ok. now it shows "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Coonfiguration.KeyValueConfigurationElement' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Textbox'"

Comment: Use the Textbox.Text property.

Comment: Thanks. It worked with slight modification. `config.AppSettings.Settings["Configpath"]` 's Value property shoould be used at right hand side.